# How do I add custom cells for a tableView which has been added on top of a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used a tableView (myTableView) on a usual UIViewController class. I wish to use reusable cells in this tableView to save memory. I did not create separate XIB and dragged and dropped a tableView component on to the viewController.
The cells have been created with a new class *HistoryTableViewCell* of type UITableViewCell and this class also has an XIB.
I have also created a tableViewCell and its XIB and used the following code in the `tableView(_,cellForRowAt:)` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "historyReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! HistoryTableViewCell
    cell.meetingDateLabel.text = historyArray![indexPath.section]

    return cell
}
```

This line of code works fine with a tableViewController when I add the following line in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

But the `tableView.register` property cannot be used with a tableView. How do I make use of the reusable cells here?

Comment: Please take more effort when asking questions. No, this will not work on a view controller or a table view controller. You identifiers don't match. To answer your question; absolutely same way as you do with a table view controller.

Comment: I think you used different reusableIdentifier.register and dequeable cell have different identifier name

Comment: If you have only one table view delete the XIB and design **all** cells in the table view in Interface Builder

Comment: @Desdenova thank you for the suggestion, the question has been updated. I found out the answer to the question. Instead of using tableView.register(_), _mytableView.register()_ must be used and the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple. I figured it out after reading a few of the other answers.

All I needed was to replace this line:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

with this one:

```
UITableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
```

Since there is no table view by the name *tableView*, you need to access the *UITableView* class.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your xib is ok, everything works fine and the only thing left is to register the `nib`.

First declare your table view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` :

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HistoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyReuseIdentifier")
```

Also check your tableView's `dataSource` and `delegate`.

Comment: This works. I can reuse the cells in the tableView. Also, you can change the name from tableView to any other name (eg: myTableView) and the property can be accessed directly as......... myTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "HistoryTableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "historyReuseIdentifier"))

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reuse the cells thats ok, to use them you need to register it first..suppose you have multiple tableView in a single ViewController, then you have to register each cell with respective tableView.
just register the tableViewCell with respective tableView and use its reusableIdentifier which you have used while registering the tabelViewcell.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create it directly in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` like this. Here no need of `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", ...` line.

```
//And replace names with your names
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell") as? TableViewCell
if cell == nil {
     cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell",owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? TableViewCell
}
```

Comment: @ Desdenova, can you please explain why it is wrong. I'm following this code up to now.

Comment: No you can't, you can't return an optional from that method.